# Invertible matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am trying to prove OR to rule out the following sentence and i'm kind of stuck.

1. if A,B are Invertible matrix, then A+B is also an Invertible matrix?

what are the steps to prove OR to rule it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take for example

$$A=I\;,\;\;B=-I$$

Comment: $\;-I=$ the unit matrix with entries multiplied by $\;-1\;$ . Always invertible, of course, just as the unit matrix $\;I\;$ itself.

Comment: when A=I and B=-I I got that A+B=0 and its not invertible so this sentence is false. thank you!